# How can I query mulltiple tables and order by date in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table

I have a controller with 2 queries :

```
def index
  @invoices = current_company.invoices.order(billed_at: :desc)

  @user_invoices = current_user.invoices.order(billed_at: :desc)
end
```

in my view I have a table with a `if` to render the table and sometimes I have both to display,
I have a column date in this table,
How can I sort this table by date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Rails way - just connect them and sort:

```
def index
    @invoices = current_company.invoices.order(billed_at: :desc)
    @user_invoices = current_user.invoices.order(billed_at: :desc)
    @all_invoices = (@invoices + @user_invoices).sort_by {|a| a.created_at}.reverse
end
```

In your view:

```
- @all_invoices.each do |invoice|
  = invoice.id
```

So simple!

---

Alternatively if you want to display either company OR user invoices:

```
def index
  if current_company.present?
    @invoices = current_company.invoices.order(billed_at: :desc)
  elsif current_user.present?
    @user_invoices = current_user.invoices.order(billed_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

Comment: Also do you know how to check if my invoice is in company or user in the view, something like : 
`- if invoice.User?`

Comment: Just to point out that this isn't performant... you're loading all the invoices in memory and sorting them in memory.  To find out if the invoice is a a user invoice, do `current_user.invoices.include?(invoice)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a union of the two queries and order that...

```
def index
  invoices = current_company.invoices
  user_invoices = current_user.invoices
  @all_invoices = Invoice.from("(#{invoices.to_sql} UNION #{user_invoices.to_sql}) AS invoices").order(billed_at: :desc)
end
```

Then you just iterate through `@all_invoices`.  You could test if the invoice is company or user by an if statement `if invoice.company == current_company`

Comment: Humm Maybe it should be something like this : 
`@all_invoices = Invoice.from("('(#{invoices.to_sql}') UNION User.from('(#{user_invoices.to_sql}') AS invoices").order(billed_at: :desc)`
But i'm stuck with the quotes do you know how to format it ?

Comment: No, it's invoices and invoices, getting User in it, I can't see that working...